# Intel Fortran error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

Accept my apologies for probably asking such a basic question here, I am new to programming with Intel Fortran so I think there is something missing or wrongly organized that I am not aware of in this case. I would be grateful if someone can help me in this regard.

The problem is that I see the following errors when compiling my code, while I believe that I have declared the derived type variables `cr` and `me` correctly.

```
error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [CR]

error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [ME]
```

My code contains a Module named `InputData` which contains the definition of the derived type `grid` and declaration of the derived type variables `cr` and `me` of type `grid`. I make use of these definitions in the main program using a `USE` statement. The error refers to a line in the main program which `CALLs` an internal subroutine that uses `cr` and “me” as input argument (`INTENT(IN)`). Surprisingly, I use exactly the same way for declaring the derived type variable `ls` of type `Levelset` defined in Module `OutputData` using a `USE` statement in the Main program and get no error on that variable in the same subroutine. Adding a `USE InputData` statement to the subroutine `ComputeLS` also did not address the issue. The structure of the program units are as follow:

```
MODULE InputData
    TYPE grid                                               
        REAL, DIMENSION(:,:), POINTER :: nodes 
        INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), POINTER :: connectivity    
    END TYPE grid
    TYPE(grid) :: cr, me

    CONTAINS
        …
END MODULE InputData

MODULE OutputData
   TYPE levelset                                                  
       REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: f, g       
   END TYPE levelset    
   …
   TYPE(levelset) :: ls                

   CONTAINS
   …
END MODULE OutputData

PROGRAM Main
    USE InputData
    USE OutputData
    USE Timing
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), POINTER :: ed
    …

    CALL ComputeLS(me, cr, ed, ls)    <========= error #6633 refers to this line    
    …

    CONTAINS

    ! INTERNAL PROCEDURES
    SUBROUTINE ComputeLS(me, cr, ed, ls)

        USE MathCalc
        IMPLICIT NONE

        TYPE(grid), INTENT(IN) :: me, cr
        INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(IN) :: ed

        TYPE(levelset), INTENT(OUT) :: ls
        …

    END SUBROUTINE ComputeLS
    …
END PROGRAM Main
```

I tried to remove all modules and include all type definitions and variable declarations in the Main program instead of in separate modules. But unfortunately the errors still exist.

Comment: How is `ed` defined in the main program?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: "ed" is defined as follow; however since the error mentions [cr] or [me] at the end it seems the problem might not be associated with "ed". INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:), POINTER :: ed

Comment: Mhm, I cannot see an error from what you posted, although the combination of internal procedures and modules is confusing me (and maybe the compiler as well). Can you put `ComputeLS` into a module (and  e.g. `use InputData, only: grid`)? Also, a compilable example would be nice ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderVogt: Thanks. I tried to remove all modules and include all type definitions and variable declarations in the Main program instead of in separate modules. But unfortunately the errors still exist.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Thank you. I also used to think the problem is due to similarity of the names of dummy and actual arguments. I changed the dummy arguments to "cr_grid" and "me_grid" but the errors still exist. Does it indicate compiler wackiness? Do you have any comments?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: anyways, Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a known compiler bug, ID DPD200250382, that is fixed for our upcoming 15.0 release, but your partial example differs a bit from the problem description. Are you using our Windows compiler and have Diagnostics > Check Routine Interfaces enabled? If so, try setting that option to No and see what happens.

If that doesn't help, I'd like to see a complete test case.

Comment: Thank you Steve. Check Routine Interfaces was set to No by default. So the error occurs while that setting is disabled. Could you let me know how I can send a complete case to you?

Comment: Is there anywhere in this site that I can upload a complete case for you?

Comment: You can attach a test case to a post in our user forum at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-windows A zip file is best if there is more than one source.

Comment: Hi Steve. I have attached a test case to this post at intel forum.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/518465

Comment: And you got an answer there.